# AttributeError: 'Russian' object has no attribute 'entity'

Tags: python, spacy

Пытаюсь в *spacy* добавить новый ярлык для браузеров.
Пример кода из книги (всё, кроме текста про браузер):

```
LABEL = 'BROWSER'
# Обучающий набор
TRAIN_DATA = [
    ('Мне нравится Гугл-Браузер.', {
        'entities': [(12, 25, LABEL)]
    }),
    ('Я люблю апельсины', {
        'entities': []
    })
]
# Получение экземпляра компонента ner
ner = nlp.get_pipe('ner')
# Добавляем новую метку
ner.add_label(LABEL)
# Отключаем другие контейнеры, чтобы во время обучения обновлялся
# только контейнер с подписями
nlp.disable_pipes('parser')


optimizer = nlp.entity.create_optimizer()  # <-- здесь ошибка 

import random
for i in range(25):
    random.shuffle(TRAIN_DATA)
    for text, annot in TRAIN_DATA:
        nlp.update([text], [annot], sgd=optimizer)
```

При запуске получаю:

```
optimizer = nlp.entity.create_optimizer()
                ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Russian' object has no attribute 'entity'
```

Почитал на [гитхабе](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/6644). Вариант с заменой на `nlp.get_pipe("ner")` не сработал. Как решить данную проблему на 3.7.3 версии *spacy* ?